# Magento 2.4.2 - PayPal issues - A wrong PayPal Express Checkout Token is specified

Tags: magento2.4, paypal, magento2.4.2, paypal-standard, token

We have a problem with our Magento 2.4 website with PayPal All-in-One Payment Solution (Website Payment Standard) payment method. Some of our customers are getting an error when trying to make a payment, the error message says:

```
“A wrong PayPal Express Checkout Token is specified.”
```

The error is presented to the customer after they were redirected to PayPal, logged in to their account and attempted to make a payment by clicking on the “Pay Now” button. Instead of being redirected back to our website’s success page, they are getting redirected back to their shopping cart with a message of “A wrong PayPal Express Checkout Token is specified.”. This is not impacting all our customers; however, the numbers are increasingly impacting our revenue.

I can't find a solution that works.

Comment: Hey greg u found a solution for this? Maybe i have same problem.